# Use ScrollView Object in another class

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

Please HELP ME !!

There are two classes, FirstViewCtrl and SecondViewCtrl. In FirstViewCtrl, i have UIView and i have placed an `UIScrollVIew` inside that ``. And in the SecondViewCtrl i have UIView(Consists of 3 TextField).

Now, i have linked that `UIView` from the SecondViewCtrl to the UIScrollView in the FirstViewCtrl `[_bgScrollView addSubview:SecondViewCtrl.view];`

Everything works fine until now.
I want to achieve a small task here, when the user clicks the TextField , the Keyboard Layout pops up and the Background screen should move up( I mean the Keyboard should not hide the TextField).
I have achieved it before but here its looks little different for me.
Because the UIScrollView is in the FirstViewCtrl and the TextField are in the SecondViewCtrl(which is UIView). I can get the textFieldShouldReturn in the SecondViewCtrl. How to move the BG Screen here ??

In simple, `_bgScrollView` is in FirstViewCtrl but i am handling the TextField in the SecondViewCtrl. How can i move the Background when the user select the TextField ?
I am really confused here , please help me !!!!

Comment: You're probably going to need to post more in-depth and more readable information, but does applying your `CGAffineTransform` (assuming you used CG anims) to `SecondViewCtrl` do any good?

Comment: Please post some code, it's much easier to understand than an explanation.

Comment: I will post some code, and FYI , the code is working, all i need is to move the Background when the Keyboard Layout pops up, and see the Second paragraph above.

Comment: IN FirstViewCtrl
    
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
    
    _bgScroll.scrollEnabled = YES ;
    [self layoutSubViews];
    
    }
    -(void) layoutSubViews {
    
    SecondViewCtrl* second = [[SecondViewCtrl alloc] init];
    [_bgScroll addSubView:second.View];
    
    }

Comment: IN SecondViewCtrl
    
    -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
    
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        NSLog(@"Text Editing");    
        return YES;
        
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general procedure for preventing the keyboard from covering up the text field is described in the [*Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7), with example code.  You need to subscribe to the keyboard show/hide notifications and adjust the `contentInset` property of your scroll view.

If you don't want your second view controller to know about your first view controller, you can just walk up the view hierarchy to find the scroll view.  For example:

```
- (UIScrollView *)scrollViewContainingView:(UIView *)view {
    for ( ; view; view = view.superview) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
            return (UIScrollView *)view;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the _bgScrollView (`UIScrollView`) in SecondViewController by just creating _bgScrollView as a `property` of your FirstViewController.

```
in FirstViewController.h

UIScrollView *_bgScrollView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *_bgScrollView;

in FirstViewController.m 

@synthesize *_bgScrollView;
```

now you can access _bgScrollView in your SecondViewController by using the _bgScrollView as a property of FirstViewController. Also to scroll the _bgScrollView you can use this function -

```
- (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView {  
    CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;  
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];  

    CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 200;     

    CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;  
    if (y < 0) {  
        y = 0;  
    }  
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];  

}
```

Comment: Sorry sir am not getting you, how to use it in the SecondViewCtrl ??

Comment: Actually i planned to use the UIScrollView object in the SecondViewCtrl so that i can scroll up the view when the Keyboard appears.

Comment: are your FirstViewController and SecondViewController part of a UINavigation Controller ?